# Canvas clearRect works only first time in loop, what's happened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

this is not full code, other parts is just curly brackets and some functions.
It is main part of what to be done in loop. I want to get rectangles with border radius like angles to see content under canvas throught them. But I get clearRect only first time. Or may be they just not shown because loop works all times I needed.

```
 function draw() {
            $document = $(document);
            canvas.width = $document.width();
            canvas.height = $document.height();

            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0, 0.6)";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            var $layer = $('#hint-layer'),
                $arrows = $('.arrows', $layer);

            $arrows.empty();

            $(options.selector).each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                roundedRect(ctx,
                    $this.offset().left -5,
                    $this.offset().top -5,
                    $this.outerWidth() + 10,
                    $this.outerHeight() + 10
                    ,10);

                ctx.clip();
                ctx.clearRect(
                    $this.offset().left -5,
                    $this.offset().top -5,
                    $this.outerWidth() + 10,
                    $this.outerHeight() + 10
                );
    }

    function roundedRect(ctx,x,y,width,height,radius){
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(x,y+radius);
          ctx.lineTo(x,y+height-radius);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x,y+height,x+radius,y+height);
          ctx.lineTo(x+width-radius,y+height);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+width,y+height,x+width,y+height-radius);
          ctx.lineTo(x+width,y+radius);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+width,y,x+width-radius,y);
          ctx.lineTo(x+radius,y);
          ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x,y,x,y+radius);
          ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: you are accumulating a lot of clipPaths without removing them in your loop. The only ways to do so are to reset the full contet (done when you change the canvas width/height and with the save and restore function. But what you are doing would be way easier with [globalCompositeOperation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation) source-out

Comment: I meant `destination-out`, not `source-out`... half asleep comments...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the clip using ctx.save and ctx.restore

```
$(options.selector).each(function() {
    var jQ =$(this);
    roundedRect(ctx,
        jQ .offset() .left - 5,
        jQ .offset() .top - 5,
        jQ .outerWidth() + 10,
        jQ .outerHeight() + 10
        ,10
    );
    ctx.save(); // save current unclipped state
    ctx.clip();
    ctx.clearRect(
        jQ .offset() .left - 5,
        jQ .offset() .top - 5,
        jQ .outerWidth() + 10,
        jQ .outerHeight() + 10
    );
    ctx.restore(); // remove the clip by restoring to unclipped state.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CanvasContext2D `clip` method calls do accumulate when you call it successively.

The way it does, makes any new call will have incidence only where it collapses with previously clipped parts.

Since a graphic worths 1000 words I have some trouble to find this morning, here is one :

```js
var ctx1 = c.getContext('2d');
var c2 = c.cloneNode();
var ctx2 = c2.getContext('2d');
ctx1.strokeStyle = '#CCC';

roundedRect(ctx2, 20, 40, 50, 50, 10);
ctx2.clip();
ctx2.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

roundedRect(ctx1, 20, 40, 50, 50, 10);
ctx1.stroke();
// make a new overlapping clip
roundedRect(ctx2, 60, 60, 50, 50, 10);
ctx2.clip();
ctx2.fillStyle = 'green';
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

roundedRect(ctx1, 60, 60, 50, 50, 10);
ctx1.stroke();

// make a new completely off clip
roundedRect(ctx2, 160, 90, 50, 50, 10);
ctx2.clip();
ctx2.fillStyle = 'blue';
ctx2.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

roundedRect(ctx1, 160, 90, 50, 50, 10);
ctx1.stroke();

ctx1.drawImage(c2, 0, 0);

function roundedRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y + radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + height - radius);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x + radius, y + height);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y + height);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width, y + height - radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + radius);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width - radius, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x, y + radius);
  //          ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Now, the only two ways to remove a clipping area are by resetting the whole context, which is done by setting either the `width` or `height` parameters of your canvas, or by calling `ctx.save()` before the `clip()`, and `ctx.restore()` once you don't need it anymore.
However, I'd go against `clip` in general, when it can be avoided : When drawing shapes that are not on the pixel grid, the browser will create some anti-aliasing artifacts that will cross the clipped area, and will accumulate if you draw multiple times at the same position, which can [ruin your drawings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40499791/3702797), + save/restore will save all your context's properties, which is often not needed + it's often hard to maintain which state you have saved/restore.

Instead, one should prefer [`globalCompositeOperation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation). Since what you want is a custom shaped eraser, the `destination-out` compositing mode is what you need :

```js
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
// start with a fully black canvas
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
// set the gCO to source-out
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
// custom eraser
roundedRect(ctx, 20, 40, 50, 50, 10);
ctx.fill()
roundedRect(ctx, 60, 60, 50, 50, 10);
ctx.fill()
roundedRect(ctx, 160, 90, 50, 50, 10);
ctx.fill();
// reset our gCO
ctx.globalCompositeOpeartion = 'source-over';


function roundedRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x, y + radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y + height - radius);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y + height, x + radius, y + height);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width - radius, y + height);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y + height, x + width, y + height - radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x + width, y + radius);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x + width, y, x + width - radius, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + radius, y);
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x, y + radius);
  //          ctx.stroke();
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: ivory;
  }
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```